# Java MySQL query slower than expected

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to connect to my MySQL database using Java. Here is the code:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
java.sql.Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
stmt.execute("SELECT row_1, row_2, row_3, row_4 FROM dataset where row_5 is null and row_6 is null limit 100");
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("That took " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
while (rs.next()) {
   System.out.println(rs.getString("row_1"));
}
stmt.close();
```

The table 'dataset' is 5 million rows, and is indexed on primary(row_1, row_2, row_3, row_4), and a second index (row_5 and row_6).

Uncached, this query takes 1.9 ms using SequelPro for Mac (database management software). However when I run the code above in Java, it takes about 1800 ms (uncached). Please let me know if it's just Java that's slow or there is something I can do to optimise the query in Java, because it works perfectly fine using SequelPro or using other scripting languages.

Comment: When you executed the query in sequelPro, did you account for the connection time to the DB like you do in your code?

Comment: How do you measure time?

Comment: MySQL works slower on mac. Try to make virtual machine with linux(centos, ubuntu) and install mysql on it.

Comment: @Pedromarce - yes, I only timed the stmt.execute() line.

Comment: @KarolS - I measured time using System.currentTimeMillis(); (see edited code)

Comment: @Meiblorn - I am executing the Java statement in an Ubuntu environment. I am actually connecting SequelPro to a MySQL DB set up on my Ubuntu environment.

Answer (score 0):

do you execute this as a single unit of code in a main method as standalone program? You should be aware of a "cold" jvm, which can result in strong startup performance impact. Similar you (I) dont know about the source code of java.sql.Statement.java. We dont know if there might be lazy intialization of members at any time on executing the query. You do some processing before you measure time, you can use different query to prevent cashing.